# Proof two index sets are equal

Tags: summation, proof-writing

I'm having trouble proving these two sums are equal with any change of variables, I must be missing something obvious but cannot see it. Any comments appreciated. 
$$
\sum_{m=1}^{L-1} \sum_{j=m-L+1}^{m-1} f(L-m,m,j) = \sum_{m=1}^{L-1} \sum_{j=m-L+1}^{m-1} f(L-m+j,m-j,-j)
$$
for $L \ge 2$.

["Proof" by wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%7Bm%3D1%7D%5E%7B10-1%7D%20sum_%7Bj%3Dm-10%2B1%7D%5E%7Bm-1%7D%20f(10-m,m,j)%20-%20%20sum_%7Bm%3D1%7D%5E%7B10-1%7D%20sum_%7Bj%3Dm-10%2B1%7D%5E%7Bm-1%7D%20f(10-m%2Bj,m-j,-j))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nothing is given about $f$, the equality of the sums implies the equality of the individual terms, which in turn implies the equality of the individual indices. Thus, using primes for the indices on the right-hand side:

$$m=m'-j'\;,$$
$$j=-j'\;.$$

Now you can check that substituting the limits for $m'$ and $j'$ yields the limits for $m$ and $j$.

Comment: thanks, though I'm not sure how to substitute m = m' - j' in the first summation, before j' is bound as a variable.

Comment: @anonymous_21321: You want the lower and upper bound of $m$, so you need to use the upper and lower bounds of $j'$, respectively (since it's subtracted). So for the lower bound of $m$, $j'=m'-1$, so $m=m'-j'=1$, as expected, and for the upper bound of $m$, $j'=m'-L+1$, so $m=m'-j'=L-1$, also as expected. Then for the inner summation you just need $j=-j'=m-m'$, and since $m'$ runs from $1$ to $L-1$, $j$ runs from $m-(L-1)$ to $m-1$, again as expected.

Comment: @anonymous_21321: You can think of it as a trapezoid in $(j,m)$ space, which the transformation maps onto itself, which you can also check geometrically.

Comment: got it, thanks for clarifying!